# Difference between kernel linear regression and non-parametric regression

Tags: regression, nonparametric, linear

A quick perplexity popped up in my mind while reading about *non-parametric* linear regression.

In linear regression, we model our response $\textbf{y} \sim \mathcal{N}(X\beta, \sigma^2I)$ so basically we try to estimate a linear function of the form

$$f_\beta(\textbf{x}_i) =\textbf{x}_{i,1}\beta_1, \dots, \textbf{x}_{i,p}\beta _p$$

while in non-parametric regression we allow more possibilities for the structure of $f$ and the response is modeled as

$$\textbf{y} \sim \mathcal{N}(f(x), \sigma^2I)$$

with $f$ respecting some smoothness assumptions.

What it's not too clear to me is what is the main difference between kernel linear regression and non-parametric one. It is well known that the word **linear** in linear regression refers to the parameters, so one typically applies a non-linear feature transformation $\phi : \mathbb{R}^p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ to the **features** and then searches for some hyperplane fitting the data (brought in higher dimension by the map $\phi$).

Comment: Your characterizations of linear regression and non-parametric regression are not what one would expect: they both appear to be (extremely) limited ones.  Thus, reviewing some of our [posts about non-parametric models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=parametric) might resolve this question for you.

Comment: Aren’t they exactly what is meant for linear and non parametric regression? Could you provide more details please?

Comment: "Non-parametric" refers to distributional assumptions.  Your characterization would correspond either to semi-parametric regression (if a wide set of possible $f$ is contemplated) or a parametric regression (if $f$ is finitely parameterized).  Your characterization of linear regression is unusually restrictive in specifying Normal responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *parametric model* has fixed number of parameters, in case of [*non-parametric model*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/268638/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-a-parametric-and-non-parametric-model), the number of parameters grows with the size of the data. What follows, with a parametric model we need to make stronger assumptions about the distribution of the data, while in case of the non-parametric model, it is "learned from the data" to greater degree, but the practical differences may be blurry in some cases. That is why models such as Gaussian processes [are considered](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46588/why-are-gaussian-process-models-called-non-parametric) as non-parametric, no matter that they make distributional assumptions and have parameters.

[Kernel regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_regression) is one of the non-parametric regression models, so it cannot differ from non-parametric models. It is a model that uses kernels to approximate the expected value of the distribution of the data. Other non-parametric models may use different ways of achieving this, for example in case of [$k$-NN regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) the predicted mean would be just an average of the $k$ closest neighbors of the datapoint.